# Mark date as booked in fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/  to display a full calendar to show events from a DB via json.  I need to mark a date as booked by changing the color of the calender cell.

So im guessing I need something like

```
If (date == booked){
 $(element).css("backgroundColor", "red");
}
```

Here is the code for populating the calendar.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  editable: false,

  events: {
    url: '{{URL::to('/json')}}',
    type: 'GET',

  },

   '': 'h(:mm)t' ,// uppercase H for 24-hour clock


  loading: function(bool) {
    if (bool) $('#loading').show();
    else $('#loading').hide();
  }

});

});
```

Here is my json object

```
    public function json()
{
    $bookings = Booking::all();
    //dd($bookings);
    foreach ($bookings as $b)


        $data[] = ['title'=>$b->status,
                 'start'=> $b->event_date .' ' .$b->start_time,
                 'end'=>$b->event_date .' ' .$b->end_time,
                 'description'=>'',
                 'color'=>'',
                 'status'=>$b->status,
                 'backgroundColor' => ($b->status ==='confirmed'?'#FFC0CB' : '#FFA500'),
                 'slotMinutes'=>'10',
                 'allDay'=>false];
    //return $bookings;
    return $data;


}
```

Ideally I'd like to send an array of dates I need to mark as booked. 
If someone can nudge me in the correct direction I'd really appriciated it.

Thanks

Comment: Need to view some coding of that calender.

Comment: Could you explain about `{{URL::to('/json')}}` ?

Comment: Im using Laravel to return appointments from a DB as json.  That's just the url to json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I solved it.

```
       eventRender: function (event, element, monthView) { 
          if (event.title == "booked") { 
         var date = $.fullCalendar.formatDate( event.start , 'yyyy-MM-dd'  );//event.start;

     $('.fc-day[data-date="' + date + '"]').addClass('booked'); 

    }
  },
```